# When nginx accesses the secondary directory, the response content is the same

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

When I access nginx with the following configuration, the response files are all the same

```
 worker_processes 1;
    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }

    http {
        include       mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;
      upstream tomcat_01 {
        server 192.168.6.103:9763 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=600;
      }

      upstream tomcat_02 {
        server 192.168.6.103:9763 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=600;
      }

      upstream default {
        server 192.168.6.106:9763 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=600;
      }

      server {
          listen 81;
          server_name  localhost;
          set $group default; 
          if ($remote_addr ~ "192.168.20.52") {
            set $group tomcat_01;
          }

        location /{
           proxy_pass http://$group/static/;
           proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
           proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           index  index.html index.htm;
       }
    }
    }
```

**When I visit http://192.168.6.103:81/, the static file css, js response content are all the same content. How can I solve it? Thank you**
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, if you're serving the static files from your proxy server as well, just use proxy_pass instead of alias:

```
location ~* \.(png|gif|css|js)$ {
     proxy_pass http://$group$request_uri;
}
```

Old answer (works if static files are on the same server as NGINX): You can do a location match based on the file types and specify the filepath using alias:

```
location ~* \.(png|gif|css|js)$ {
     alias /path/to/your/static/files/;
}
```

Comment: I added the configuration file according to your method, but there is still a problem accessing the static file.Access all static files, the server responds not to the static file itself, is the home page

Comment: Static files are also on the server being proxied.

Comment: The home page address of the proxy server is as follows http://192.168.6.103:9763/static The proxy server static file address is as follows http://192.168.6.103:9763/static/assets/js/StackBlur.js

Comment: This is a new configuration file, but all responses from the proxy server are the same.worker_processes 1;
 server {
      listen 81;
      server_name  localhost;
      set $group default; 
      if ($remote_addr ~ "192.168.20.52") {
        set $group tomcat_02;
      }

    location /{
       proxy_pass http://$group/static/;
       proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
  
   }
  
  location ~* \.(png|gif|css|js)$ {
     alias http://$group/static;
  } 
}

Comment: ok, then just use proxy_pass instead of alias, updated answer posted

Comment: No matter how you modify it, the static files and images of the proxy server's response are still the same.

Comment: Then perhaps the problem is with your server serving the static files, not the proxy.